# iOS sharing data between viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, data-sharing

I want to share some data (an array of custom objects)
 from different ViewController, when tab changed.

[image]

1 = `TabController`
2 = `ViewController`
3 = `ViewController`
4 = `SplitViewController`
5 = `MapView`
6 = `ViewController`
7 = `TableViewController`

I want to share data between: 
7 to 3, 7 to 2

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
class DataSource {

    static let sharedInstance = DataSource()

    var data: [AnyObject] = []

}
```

Usage:

```
DataSource.sharedInstance.data
```

Comment: I already tried this but if i change the tab the data from 7 are lost

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution is creating a view bag to hold data to be shared between VC:

```
import Foundation

class ViewBag
{
    internal static var internalDictionary = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()

    class func get(key: String) -> AnyObject?
    {
        return internalDictionary[key]
    }

    class func add(key: String, data: AnyObject)
    {
        internalDictionary[key] = data
    }
}

class MyClass
{

}

// Example

let myClassArray = [MyClass(),MyClass(),MyClass(),MyClass()]

ViewBag.add("myKey", data: myClassArray)

ViewBag.get("myKey")?.count // You must do a proper casting here
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the `data`?A string?`NSNotification` is best.A few data?Save to NSUserDefaults.A lot of data?Save to file and read it.
Here is example code for find vc along view controller chain:

```
let vc7 = UIViewController()
let tabBarVC = vc7.splitViewController?.tabBarController
let vc2 = tabBarVC?.viewControllers?[1]
let vc3 = tabBarVC?.viewControllers?[2]
```

Comment: Thats not helpful at all to throw around some nice keywords. Additionally is never a good idea to work around with NSUserDefaults for this kind of use case

Comment: You can also get 3/2 along view controller chain.First,get split vc.Second,get tab bar vc.Last,get 2/3 in tab bar vc's `viewControllers`.

Comment: An array of custom objects

Comment: @glace I know.But his question was not very clear and I updated my answer.

Comment: @Lumialxk Can u please explain a little bit more i am a rookie on swift/ios