# How to share data in different class

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get data from firebase. Then use (prepareForSegue) to set value for next UIView.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ToContent" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            firstTB = segue.destinationViewController as! FirstTabBar
            firstTB.clickedRow = indexPath.row
        }
    }
}
```

FirstTabBar is a TabBarController which contains 3 UIView.
How can these 3 UIView classes get that value from FirstTabBar class?

Comment: use sharedInstance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494722/ios-sharing-data-between-viewcontrollers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegation. I will explain with a bit simpler example with two tab bars but you can transform it to your needs.

First of all, we have to create a protocol and a function that we want to be executed in our desired view controller.

```
protocol DataDelegate: class {

    func didReceiveData(data: String)
}
```

Let's say we have **FirstViewController** which is for the first tabBar and **SecondViewController** for the second tabBar. In the **SecondViewController** we have to declare a weak variable for our delegate.

```
// In SecondViewController
weak var dataDelegate: DataDelegate?
```

In the **FirstViewController** we have to conform to the **UITabBarControllerDelegate**(do not forget to set the delegate to self in **viewDidLoad** `self.tabBarController?.delegate = self`) and use the delegate method `tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController)`

```
// MARK: - TabBarControllerDelegate

extension FirstViewController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        if let secondViewController = viewController as? SecondViewController {
            secondViewController.dataDelegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

As we can see **viewController** is the ViewController that we have tapped on(in our case **SecondViewController**). We have to cast it to SecondViewController so we have access to it's properties and set **dataDelegate** to self.

Now we are obligated to conform to the **DataDelegate** protocol. We have only one function that we have to implement - **didReceiveData()**.

```
// MARK: - DataDelegateProtocol

extension FirstViewController: DataDelegate {

    func didReceiveData(data: String) {
        print(data)
    }
}
```

Finally, in our **SecondViewController** we must tell where we want that function to be executed. I will do it **viewDidAppear** but you can wherever you need to.

```
// In SecondViewController
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.dataDelegate?.didReceiveData("data")
}
```

This guy explains delegation well [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BcBu30thIA). Hope you got it.

Answer (score 2):

Simple!

Just pass the data via the segue; assume there are two controllers, firstController and secondController, and the data is theDataToPass which is a class of CoolData

In the controller you are coming from

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let second = segue.destinationController as! SecondController
    second.representedObject = self.theDataToPass
}
```

and in the controller you are going to

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    self.thePassedData = self.representedObject as! CoolData
}
```